# How to remove slideup and slidedown feature from opencart 1.5.5.1 checkout page?

Tags: php, opencart, checkout

How to remove slideup and slidedown feature from opencart 1.5.5.1 checkout page ?

I want all form to be shown once the page loads without continue option.

Opencart Version :- 1.5.5.1

Currently default has continue option to move to next form, i want to remove continue option and just display all form at a once.

For Demo , You can go to here > http://demo.opencart.com/

Add any product and Click on Checkout, and than go to http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout

You will see everything coming in Slide UP and down jquery feature, I want to remove them and bring all form @ once.

Thanks

Comment: Please some one help ! 

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried, what didn't work. What exactly are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy, if you try it yourself and if you don't have good enough knowledge of opencart code, you will probably break something, that's why one-page checkout extensions are so expensive ( 50$ - 100$ ), you can try asking this question http://forum.opencart.com , it belongs there, this question will probably get closed here.